# Transparency when using ‘drawPixel’ on Pixmap?

Tags: java, libgdx

### Background

I am creating an application where I manually lay out [a texture atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas). The whole point is that the image itself isn’t supposed to be transparent—it has a consistent background color that is then supposed to be removed in the code.

The problem I’m having is that I can’t seem to be able to remove pixels—make them transparent—from the `Pixmap` I’m working on. I’ve made sure to use [`RGBA_8888`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.Format.html#RGBA8888) for my `Pixmap`’s `Format`, which is sure to support transparency.

### Problem

Here’s the piece of code I’m having trouble with:

```
pixmap.drawPixel(x, y, 0x00000000);
```

Quite obviously, `0x00000000` would be zero—even if converted from hex to base ten—seriously, it’s the same number!

From my observations, I’ve noticed that the `drawPixel` method draws a pixel onto the current one. What I want is for it to become transparent. Using the aforementioned piece of code, it draws transparency onto something that isn’t transparent—ending up changing nothing. As if you add nothing to something, the something remains.

### Research

As usual, I’ve done some research on my own. Here on *Stackoverflow* I haven’t managed to find anything of use. The only things I know is the things mentioned above that I’ve managed to find out by observing the `Pixmap` and its `drawPixel` method.

### Moreover

Perhaps someone can point me in the right direction as to how you’d make a pixel of a `Pixmap` transparent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you already discovered, you can't draw a blended transparent pixel over the existing pixel, because you can't see anything. So first you need to disable Pixmap blending.

```
Pixmap.setBlending(Pixmap.Blending.None); // before you start drawing pixels.

pixmap.drawPixel(x, y, 0x00000000);
// And all pixels you want to draw

Pixmap.setBlending(Pixmap.Blending.SourceOver); // if you want to go back to blending
```

If you want to maintain the RGB of the existing pixel, you have to get the current pixel color and manually black out the alpha component only:

```
pixmap.drawPixel(x, y, pixmap.getPixel(x, y) & 0xffffff00);
```